# Geometric Distribution Expectation via Survival Function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I'm studying Survival Functions and the book argues that they can be used to prove the Expectation of the Geometric Distribtuion in the following way:
[image]
The first equals sign is basically the definition of a Survival Function, which I get. But the next 2 I don't understand. How did the author 1)arrive at q^(n+1) and then 2)go from a summed notation to q/(1-q)?

Answer (score 0):

$P(X>n)= \sum\limits_{k=n+1}^{\infty} pq^{k}=p\frac {q^{n+1}} {1-q}=q^{n+1}$ by the formula for the sum  of a geometric series. By the same formula $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} q^{n+1}=\frac q {1-q}$.

Sum of a geometric series: $\sum\limits_{k=n}^{\infty} cr^{n}=c \frac {r^{n}} {1-r}$ if $|r| <1$.